# Find the linear transformations given 2 basis and the associated matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: tyhe]

Translation:
Being T: R3 to R2 a lineal transformation. Basis 1: ..... and Basis 2:...... ,Basis of R3 and R2 respectively. Consider:

A (associated matrix)= T B1 to B2=.....

Find:

a)T(1,1,0)B2

b) T(3,2,1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $(1,1,0)$ in the form of $B_1$ basis which is equal to $(0,1,0)_{B_1}$ . Now multiply it with $A$ to get

$$|T(1,1,0)|_{B_2} = A\cdot (0,1,0)^T = (0,1)_{B_2}$$

For part b), write $(3,2,1)$ in the form of $B_1$ basis which is equal to $(1,1,1)_{B_1}$. Now multiply this with $A$ to get

$$T(3,2,1) = A\cdot (1,1,1)^T=(0,2)_{B_2} = (2,-2)$$

Comment: yeah thanks, both of your answers are right.